# navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) doesn't deinit the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When I use `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` or when I dismiss a `UINavigationController`, the `deinit` method of my `ViewController`s does not get called. Does this mean they are not being deallocated in memory?

How can I deallocate a `UINavigationController` and all of its `ViewController`s?

Comment: Use the memory graph hierarchy feature of Xcode to see what is holding a reference to your VC.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you may have a variable somewhere that's holding a reference to the view controller. If that's the case, that variable is causing Swift to hold onto your View Controller in memory. You can do a few things to fix that:

- Set that variable to a `weak var`, which means that if its the last variable left holding a reference to something, it will be deallocated.
- Set the variable to nil when you pop the view controller. If you have no references left to the view controller, then it will be deallocated.

Sweepers comment will hopefully help you find the variable in question.